# How to create variables for substitution based on user for unique filepath in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import, read.csv

I'm writing code that I want to make generic to whoever needs to follow it.
Part of the code is reading in an excel file that the user has to download. I know that each user has a specific 6-digit unique ID, and the folder and name of the file remains the same. Is there some way for me to modify the pd.read_csv function so that it is like this:

```
USERID = '123abc'
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\USERID\Documents\Dataset.csv')
```

I keep getting stuck because there is an ' next to the r so concatenation with a constant does not seem to work.

Similarly, is there a method for code for exporting that would insert the current date in the title?

Comment: Using formated string? : f'C:\Users\{USERID}\Documents\Dataset.csv'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use are formatted strings. The `r` preceding the string literal in your code denotes that you are creating a **raw string**, which means that you aren't going to ever see the value of your variable get assigned correctly within that string. Python's docs explain what these raw strings are:

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters. ([3.10.4 Python Language Reference, Lexical Analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html))

Like Fredericka mentions in her comment, the formatted string is a great way to accomplish what you're trying to do. If you're using Python version 3.6 or greater, you can also use the `format` method on the string, which does the same thing.

```py
# set the User ID
user_id = "PythonUser1"

# print the full filepath
print("C:\\Users\\{}\\Documents\\Dataset.csv".format(user_id))

# read the CSV file using formatted string literals
my_csv = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\{user_id}\\Documents\\Dataset.csv")

# read the CSV file using the format method
my_csv = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\{}\\Documents\\Dataset.csv".format(user_id))
```

For more information, I'd recommend checking out the [official Python docs on input and output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).